# Bluz how to store session in Redis?

Tags: php, session, redis

I am using [Bluz Framework](https://github.com/bluzphp/skeleton) and want to store session in Redis, but session continue storing in file. I am using Redis 2.2.5 and Bluz 0.8.0
this is config for my environment

```
return array(
    "adapter" => "files",
    "settings" => array(
        "cache" => array(),
        "files" => array(
            "save_path" => PATH_DATA . '/sessions'
        ),
        "redis" => array(
            "host" => 'localhost'
        )
    )
);
```

and this is session adapter (I got it from debugger)

```
adapter = {Bluz\Session\Adapter\Redis}
    settings = {array}
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = "6379"
        timeout = null
        persistence = false
    handler
        socket = {resource} resource id='195' type='Redis Socket Buffer'
    prefix = "PHPSESSID"
    ttl = 1800
```

adapter created right but session writes to file. So what I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your question,
We found issue in current version of Bluz, and it was fixed in 0.9.0 release (https://github.com/bluzphp/framework/releases/tag/0.9.0)

If you are interested - we cann't reproduce this bug with Redis extension ver. 2.2.3,  but with version 2.2.5 we catched it - problem with usage of method `set()`, third parameter `timeout` should be integer type, not a string with integer value

P.S. Please use tag Bluz for quick response from our team ;)

Comment: Thank you it work!!! I tried to add tag Bluz but it isn't present in list of tags on stackoverflow and only people who have more then 1500 reputation can add new tag :(